# How to get menu ID from HMENU?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, mfc, gdi

I'm trying to override WM_HELP message for my dialog window when a user presses F1 key. The window has several buttons that display context menus via TrackPopupMenu, as well as the main menu (on top.) So there's more than just one menu in this window.

I can trap menu message as such when processing `WM_HELP`, but I need to know which context menu sent this message:

```
BOOL CMyDialog::OnHelpInfo(HELPINFO* pHelpInfo)
{
    if(pHelpInfo->iContextType == HELPINFO_MENUITEM)
    {
        HMENU hMenu = (HMENU)pHelpInfo->hItemHandle;

        //How to get menu ID from HMENU?
    }

    //...
}
```

So I need to find a way to get menu resource ID from `HMENU` -- this one that was used to create it:

[image]

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: but `pHelpInfo->iCtrlId` is identifier of the menu item

Comment: Er, read the documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773313.aspx

Comment: I don't know how you can get the Resource ID, but I can suggest you to load the menu via `CMenu* pMenu= CMenu::FromHandle(hMenu);` . But why do you need the resource ID? Having a pointer to the real object itself isn't what you want?

Comment: I need to know which menu is it. (I have 3 in that window.) I guess I can recursively search for the `pHelpInfo->iCtrlId` in all of my available menus, but that would be quite an overkill. Thus I was looking for something that seemed pretty obvious -- get menu ID from `HMENU`.

Comment: Microsoft site seems to be down too. So can't open your link.

Comment: but usually all menu *ID* is unique. for example when user press menu item - you got `WM_COMMAND` with menu *ID* in *wParam* - how you know in this case which menu item user select ? usual by *unique* *ID*. in case *WM_HELP* you got the same *ID* in `pHelpInfo->iCtrlId`. are you have not unique/duplicated *ID* ?

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to "somewhat bruteforce" it. You can approach it from the top-down. Make a function like this:

```
BOOL IsMenuItemIDInMenu(UINT nMenuID, UINT nMenuItemID)
{
    //Checks if 'nMenuItemID' belongs to 'nMenuID'
    BOOL bRes = FALSE;

    if(nMenuID &&
        nMenuItemID)
    {
        HMENU hMenu = ::LoadMenu(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(nMenuID));
        if(hMenu)
        {
            //Look for it
            bRes = __searchForMenuItem(hMenu, nMenuItemID);

            //Free menu
            ::DestroyMenu(hMenu);
        }
    }

    return bRes;
}

BOOL __searchForMenuItem(HMENU hMenu, UINT nMenuItemID)
{
    ASSERT(hMenu);

    int nCnt = ::GetMenuItemCount(hMenu);
    if(nCnt != -1)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < nCnt; i++)
        {
            //Is it a submenu
            HMENU hSubMenu = ::GetSubMenu(hMenu, i);
            if(!hSubMenu)
            {
                UINT nID = ::GetMenuItemID(hMenu, i);
                if(nID != -1 &&
                    nID == nMenuItemID)
                {
                    //Found it
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Process submenu
                if(__searchForMenuItem(hSubMenu, nMenuItemID))
                {
                    //Found it in submenu
                    return TRUE;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
```

And then when you get a menu ID that was highlighted when F1 was pressed, see which of your menus it belongs to:

```
if(pHelpInfo->iContextType == HELPINFO_MENUITEM)
{
    if(IsMenuItemIDInMenu(IDR_MENU_1, pHelpInfo->iCtrlId))
    {
    }
    else if(IsMenuItemIDInMenu(IDR_MENU_2, pHelpInfo->iCtrlId))
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. This looks like a head-on way to tackle it.

Comment: Out of curiosity: What's with the reserved symbol?

Comment: @IInspectable: I took it from an old library. Plus, a habit from a long ago too. You can rename it into a usual camel-case or whatever else works for you.

Comment: Time to change them habits then. Those symbols are [reserved](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers) for a reason. If you use them, the behavior is undefined.